# Return Index of Pixel Locations from Array

Tags: python, image, rgb

Our issue: we have an image volume stored as a 4d numpy array, or rather a 3d array of RGB values (of shape [42, 512, 512, 3]:  [z, y, x, c]). We are trying to return an index of all [z, y, x] pixel locations where the RGB values fall above a lower RGB threshold (e.g., [10, 20, 30]) and below an upper threshold (e.g., [50, 60, 70]). In this example, we want [z, y, x] indices for pixels where all of the following are true: R is between 10 and 50, G is between 20 and 60, and B is between 30 and 70.

This is what the attempt looks like:

```
RGB_array=np.asarray(only_3D)
empty_array=np.zeros(RGB_array.shape)
for c_num,cluster in enumerate(clusters):
     lowerbound=[cluster[0]-threshold, cluster[1]-threshold, cluster[2]-threshold] #lowerbound, these thresholds are based off of a k-means clustering
     upperbound=[cluster[0]+threshold, cluster[1]+threshold, cluster[2]+threshold] #upperbound
     print(f'iteration: {c_num}, lower: {lowerbound}, upper: {upperbound}')
     print(list(RGB_array[0,0,0])>=lowerbound and list(RGB_array[0,0,0])<=upperbound)
     empty_array[np.where(np.logical_and(RGB_array>=lowerbound, RGB_array<=upperbound))] = c_num+1
```

Not sure if this is on the right path, but it logically makes sense.

Comment: Do all the c (3) pixels need to fall within the range for the cluster to be counted? Either way, the general basis of the program should be to iterate (or enumerate) through the dimensions, and simply just add (the x,y,z) to the list of values. I believe you are doing this, but it is just another pov.

Comment: You'll need to check each color component separately.  Remember that [10,255,255] is less than [11,0,0], which doesn't match what you need.